# Data driven line-width in Mapbox JS GL

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I have added a geojson to my map. One of the feature's properties is called `delay` - it contains numbers between 0 and 160.  Below, I have tried to make `line-width` a function of the value in this property (using [this link as an example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/updating-choropleth/)), just as one would style color.  In fact, I would like it to be a mathematical function ( sqrt(delay) as opposed to using categories), but in either case I receive a syntax error in the console every time unexpected ")", suggesting that one cannot style line-width in the same way as color.  What would be the best workaround in Mapbox JS GL?

```
map.on('load', function () {
   map.addSource("routes", {
       "type": "geojson",
       "data": "simplify_830.geojson"
   });

   map.addLayer({
       "id": "routes",
       "type": "line",
       "source": "routes",
       "layout": {},
       "paint": {
           "line-color": "#FFA500",
           'line-width': {
               property: 'delay',
               stops: [
                   [0, 2],
                   [20, 4],
                   [40, 6],
                   [60, 8],
                   [80, 10],
                   [100, 12],
                   [120, 14],
                   [140, 16],
                   [160, 20]
               ]
           },
       "filter": ["==", "name", ""]
   });
```

Comment: Support for line paint properties is still in the works. See https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2729

Comment: Still seems to be not implemented. All the relevant issues are closed: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2729 https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3646 https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/3033 Not sure the current state exactly.

Answer (score 1):

We don't yet support data-driven styling for line properties.

We plan to add it very soon per http://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2729.

My apologies for not more clearly communicating the state of data-driven styling support. A colleague of mine is working on a support table now! https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-style-spec/pull/465

Comment: Is this still up to date? Or whats the state of this feature? The issue seem to be closed and some pull requests got merged.